# React sort a map function with two fields

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, map-function

I'm a beginner with React and i want to sorting an array by two filters :

```
{folder.actions
  .sort((a,b) => {
    return a.date_actual - b.date_actual || a.date_sched - b.date_sched
   })
  .map(action => {
   ...
```

This code doesn't work, i want to sort by descending and mixed two dates type "date_actual" and "date_sched" with map function and not :

```
...
  <Col xs={4}>
    {action.date_actual ? 
      new Date(action.date_actual).toLocaleDateString() : 
      new Date(action.date_sched).toLocaleDateString()
     }
  </Col>
...
18/04/2021 (date_sched)
03/11/2020 (date_actual)
18/04/2021 (date_sched)
03/11/2020 (date_actual)
03/11/2020 (date_actual)
03/11/2020 (date_actual)
12/04/2021 (date_sched)
03/11/2020 (date_actual)
03/11/2020 (date_actual)
```

Thanks for your time and your help !

Comment: If you have the option of adding other libraries, Lodash is a great library that provides a lot of useful utilities for working with arrays.  The `sortBy()` method is one and would easily do what you need.  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy

Comment: Your question is unclear. How does your input data look like? And, how would the output look like?

Comment: @AjeetShah, in input i have an array some entries look like date_actual: (a date), date_sched: null and others date_actual: null, date_sched: (an other date). In output, i want all dates by reverse sorting.

Comment: Instead of adding those details in a comment, please update your question to include those details (e.g. either `date_actual ` has a value or `date_sched` has a value).

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to sort based on 2 date types at once, you can use the `||` operator in your sort logic. Let's say for example you have an array like this: (I use a number for simplicities sake)

```js
const yourArray = [
  { first_date: 0 },
  { second_date: 1 },
  { first_date: 3 },
  { second_date: 2 }
];
```

What we want to achieve is this:

```js
const yourArray = [
  { first_date: 0 },
  { second_date: 1 },
  { second_date: 2 }
  { first_date: 3 },
];
```

---

You can tell javascript to use either the first date, of use the second one if that the first one does not exist.

```js
yourArray
  .sort((a, b) => (a.first_date || a.second_date) - (b.first_date || b.second_date));

// const yourArray = [
//   { first_date: 0 },
//   { second_date: 1 },
//   { second_date: 2 }
//   { first_date: 3 },
// ];
```

Comment: The sort logic may be simpler if you make a temp date field, but it is not required (e.g. there is no "have to" here)

Comment: @crashmstr Indeed, I was looking past the obvious here. Thanks for clarifying this. Appreciate it! I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your fast reply,

with this :

```
{folder.actions
  .sort((a,b) => {
     return (a.date_actual || a.date_sched) - (b.date_actual || b.date_sched)
   })
  .map(action => {
...
return (
 ...
  <Col xs={4}>
   {action.date_actual ? 
     new Date(action.date_actual).toLocaleDateString() : 
     new Date(action.date_sched).toLocaleDateString()}
  </Col>
```

I have on screen :

```
03/11/2020
18/04/2021
03/11/2020
18/04/2021
03/11/2020
03/11/2020
12/04/2021
03/11/2020
03/11/2020
```

in input in array i have :

```
date_actual: "2020-11-03 17:30:30"
date_sched: null
```

some entries are inversed, date_actual is empty and date_sched is fully

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function will always sort by the first condition, as it will always evaluate to true.
If you want sort by both fields, you have to explicitly define those conditions:

e.g.
if (a.date1 > b.date2) & (a.date2 > b.date2) return 1
and so on...